# Finding conditional distribution in multinormal case

Tags: normal-distribution

> [S]uppose that $X_1$ (sales), $X_2$ (price), $X_3$ (advertisement), and $X_4$ (sales assistants) are normally distributed with:

$$ \mu = \begin{pmatrix} 172.7 \\ 104.6 \\ 104.0 \\ 93.8 \end{pmatrix}
\text{ and }
 \Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
 1037.21 & & & \\
 -80.02 & 219.84 & & \\
 1430.70 & 92.10 & 2624.00 & \\
  271.44 & -91.58 & 210.30 &  177.36 \end{pmatrix} $$

> (These are in fact the sample mean and the sample covariance matrix but in this case we pretend that they are the true parameter values.)
>
> The conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $(X_2,X_3,X_4)$ is thus an univariate normal with mean

$$ \mu_1 + \sigma_{12} \Sigma_{22}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
  X_2 - \mu_2 \\ X_3 - \mu_3 \\ X_4 - \mu_4 \end{pmatrix}
 = 65.670 - 0.216 X_2 + 0.485 X_3 + 0.844 X_4 $$

> and variance

$$ \sigma_{11.2} = \sigma_{11} - \sigma_{12} \Sigma_{22}^{-1} \sigma_{21} = 96.671 $$

I'm trying to understand this example and can't figure out how it partition the covariance matrix. In this case, what is $\Sigma_{22}^{-1}$ ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete the top-right of the covariance matrix by reflecting the bottom-left to give

$$ \Sigma = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1037.21 &  -80.02 &  1430.7 &  271.44 \\
-80.02 &  219.84 &  92.1 &  -91.58 \\
1430.7 &  92.1 &  2624 &  210.3 \\
271.44 &  -91.58 &  210.3 &  177.36\end{array} \right)$$

$\sigma_{12}$ then apparently means the $1$st row of the matrix excluding the $1$st cell, so $$ \sigma_{12} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-80.02 &  1430.7 &  271.44 \end{array} \right)$$ and $\sigma_{21}$ is apparently the transpose of this (the $1$st column of the matrix excluding the $1$st cell)

while $\Sigma_{22}$ apparently means the covariance matrix without the $1$st row or column so

$$ \Sigma_{22} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
219.84 &  92.1 &  -91.58 \\
92.1 &  2624 &  210.3 \\
-91.58 &  210.3 &  177.36\end{array} \right)$$

with  $\Sigma_{22}^{-1}$ being its inverse

$$ \Sigma_{22}^{-1} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0.006427076  & -0.000543173 &  0.00396268 \\
-0.000543173 &  0.000467021 &  -0.000834226 \\
0.00396268 &  -0.000834226 &  0.008673545 \end{array} \right)$$

and you can check that

$$\sigma_{12} \Sigma_{22}^{-1}  \left( \begin{array}{c}
X_2 \\
X_3 \\
X_4 \end{array} \right) = -0.215782095 X_2 + 0.485189757 X_3 +0.843726149 X_4$$ which gives the coefficients in your example.  I will leave the arithmetic of the intercept and the variance to you, but it is similar matrix multiplication.